# How to enable double-click

Tags: nautilus, mouse

I can't open folders with double click anymore. Instead I have to right click and press open. How do I reenable it? I'm running Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: OMG thank you so much for that i have been right clicking and hitting open for almost a year now

Answer (score 22):

> Go to System Settings > Click on Mouse and TouchPad & Check Double Click to low

[image]

Comment: I had been struggling without double clicking. thanks for your help and you made me work eagarly more on ubuntu

Answer (score 9):

### Ubuntu 18.04

- Open **Settings** and click on the left tap **Universal Access**.
- In the bottom you will find **Double-Click delay**

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that this method of increasing double-click delay had solved my double-click problem

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 17.10 and some other versions, the setting to set the double-click speed doesn't show under the "mouse and touchpad" settings - see here:

[image: mouse and trackpad settings in Ubuntu 17.10]

However, there is a different solution or workaround:

1. Open the Activities overview and start typing Universal Access.
2. Click on Universal Access to open the panel.
3. Under Pointing & Clicking, adjust the Double-click slider to a value you find comfortable.

Source: http://ftp.labdoo.org/download/Public/manuals/help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-doubleclick.html

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/886167)

Comment: I just found a solution and turned the question into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem after reinstalling xserver `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`, since keyboard and mouse suddenly stopped working.

I tried the same with this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/295342/1201991 .
Everything was ok then.

Answer (score -1):

open startup Application Preference -> Add

- Name: **Touchpad Tap Function**
- Command : **synclient TapButton1=1 TapButton2=3 TapButton3=2**

Then click **Add**

And **reboot**