# opening folder and files

Tags: mouse

I'm having a problem with my desktop. I can't open a folder or any files by clicking on them. but if I right click and go to open it using the menu, it opens. Can someone tell me why it woun't open when i click on it?

Comment: What about double-clicking?

Answer (score 0):

Try executing this command:

```
metacity --replace &
```

It will make it work if you're using compiz. If you want compiz back, type:

```
compiz --replace &
```

and the mouse clicks will work again.

It this doesn't work for you, then try this: [How to enable double-click](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295340/how-to-enable-double-click)

Finally, it will also be a good idea to check if the same mouse works in another computer.

Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: when i run "metacity --replace &" my top bar freezes  and when I run "compiz --replace &" my top bar freeze too and i get the err "compiz (core) - Error: Failed to load plugin: ccp" and I tried the mouse and pad but I don't have a double click on. line on there.