# Issue with File and Folder Opening on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I recently installed Kubuntu (Regular Kubuntu not via WSL) and encountered some issues that I would like to describe. I believe two situations are related:

1. On my desktop, when I click on files or folders to open them, they only show a file icon (default white-colored file icon for files that do not have an icon) in the task manager. It briefly indicates loading or opening, but after a second or so, it disappears without any result. However, when I try to open files using "right click > open with," it works just fine.
2. In XDM, when it finishes downloading a file, a window pops up giving me the option to either open the downloaded file or close the window. However, when I click on "open" it does not open the file. Instead, the same thing that happens in the first situation occurs.

Additional Information:
When I hovered over the icon in the task manager, its tooltip displayed "WSL View"

My Kubuntu version info:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 23.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.104.0
Qt Version: 5.15.8
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-20-generic (64-bit)
```

Journalctl Log:

```
3069091, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
June 05 14:32:08 MBA-Desktop systemd[1579]: app-wslview-cdf714dbc9c74c90b8ec0f13602e3e21.scope: Failed to add PIDs to the scope's control group: No such process
June 05 14:32:08 MBA-Desktop systemd[1579]: app-wslview-cdf714dbc9c74c90b8ec0f13602e3e21.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
June 05 14:32:08 MBA-Desktop systemd[1579]: Failed to start app-wslview-cdf714dbc9c74c90b8ec0f13602e3e21.scope - WSLView.
```

There was already a [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/992461/1702214) asked about kinda of similar issue, but it was not specific at all.

I would greatly appreciate your help in resolving this matter.

Thank you.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running, as this will help in diagnosing your issue. As well, it appears that you're running Kubuntu via WSL, is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for the note Just edited

Comment: Which "folders" (directories) are you using? Have you recently run a graphical browser as `root`? Check the ownership and permissions. Either: Right click on the object, and select Properties; or, from the command line, `ls -ld ~/Desktop` and `ls -l ~/Desktop`. Or, to list all the files in your Home directory tree that aren't owned by you, `sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER -print0 | xargs -0  -r ls  -ld`.

Comment: What do you mean exactly, if you mean what directories I try to open on desktop I should say any directory, even the ones I made my self can't be opened and even files can't be opened from desktop, I checked the permissions and it was ok and no I did not open any browers as root.

Comment: Keep XDM out of this, focus on those files and folders. Does this happen with all files andfolders on the desktop or just with some special files?

Comment: Yes this happens with all file types and all folders in my desktop. I only brought up XDM because it gave exactly the same error in journalctl I thought It could be helpful in debugging it.