# Double-click not working and double-click speed setting missing - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad, doubleclick

I saw few answers suggesting to adjust the double-click speed, like this:

[image]

But in my case that option is missing:

[image]

I don't know if it's related, but the OS is running on Hyper-V on laptop, so it's a touchpad, not a mouse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable double-click](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295340/how-to-enable-double-click)

Answer (score 4):

- Open **Settings** and click on the left bar **Universal Acess**.
- In the bottom you will find **Double-Click delay**

[image]